# Can't Get data from Cloud Firestore in flutter app

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have created createRecord() method:

```
CollectionReference addBlog = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('blogAddress');
  Future<void> createRecord() {
    // Call the user's CollectionReference to add a new user
    return addBlog
        .add({
      'blogAddress': IfUserProfile.blog, // Stokes and Sons
    })
        .then((value) => print("Blog Added"))
        .catchError((error) => print("Failed to add Blog: $error"));
  }
```

which create the record from a textformField:

```
onChanged: (value) {
                    IfUserProfile.blog = value;
                  },
```

it work correctly it adds on Firestore correctly the collection:
[image]

Now I am trying to get this data into another screen and I call the instance:

```
CollectionReference blogAddress =
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('blogAddress');
```

and I wrap the Column where I have the data with FutureBuilder:

```
 FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
              future: blogAddress.doc().get(),
              builder: (BuildContext context,
                  AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text("Something went wrong");
                }
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data.data();
                  return Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 30,
                      ),
                      Text("Full Name: ${data['blogAddress']}"),
```

but I cant the data I get:

The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`snapshot.data.data()` is returning null.  That happens when you request a document that doesn't exist.  Your code `blogAddress.doc().get()` is never going to get a document, because `doc()` with no arguments generates a reference to a random document ID that doesn't exist yet.  If you want a specific document, you should pass the document ID to `doc()`.

```
blogAddress.doc("the-document-ID-you-want").get()
```

Comment: Ok thats clear but if into createRecord doc(id) is created randomnly by firestore so what I have to put inside get class into doc() ?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking.  If you have a new question, I suggest posting it separately along with code that isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: I added to get Class  return addBlog
        .doc('ABC123')
        .set({
      'full_name': IfUserProfile.blog,
and in this specific case the ID of the doc is  "ABC123" and it works if I put ABC123 as ID, but I want to have self generated ID how to get it ?

Comment: Please post a new question to explain in more detail where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try this,
    
      



body: StreamBuilder(
                    stream: Firestore.instance
                        .collection('blogAddress')
                        .snapshots(),
                    builder: (BuildContext context,
                        AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.data.toString()=='null')
                        return Text('');
                      if (snapshot.hasError)
                        return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                      if(snapshot.data.documents.length<1)
                        return SizedBox.shrink();
                      switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                        case ConnectionState.waiting:
                          return new Text('Loading...');
                        default:
         
                     Print("snapshotData:- "+snapshot.data.documents.toString());
                          return new ListView(
                            children: snapshot.data.documents
                                .map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                   Print("documentAll :-"+document.toString());
                      Print("document blogAddress:- "+ document['blogAddress'].toString());      

         
   return Text(document['blogAddress'].toString());
                            }).toList(),
                          );
                      }
                    },
                  )
```

Comment: are you try this your main body.

Comment: Check again,I added print statement for getting how many steps your works.